# What's the relation of db tables, models and serializers in Django REST?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am confused about the function of `serializers` in Django REST Framework. It is said in official document, [Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/):

> Serializers allow complex data such as querysets and model instances to be converted to native Python datatypes that can then be
>   easily rendered into JSON, XML or other content types. Serializers
>   also provide deserialization, allowing parsed data to be converted
>   back into complex types, after first validating the incoming data.

So in my understand, they have a relation like this:

```
database table <--> model instance(queryset) <--> serializer  <--> native Python datatypes(dict, list)  <--> JSON/XML
```

Is it right??

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question, it makes me clarify my confusion.